# Node app crashing when wrong username is entered

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../Model/UserModel");
const cryptoJS = require("crypto-js");    
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
          try {
            const user = await User.findOne({
              username: req.body.username,
            });
            !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");
            const hashedPassword = cryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
              user.password,
              process.env.PASS_SEC
            );
            const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(cryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            const inputPassword = req.body.password;
            originalPassword != inputPassword &&
              res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(500);
            console.log(error);
            res.json(error);
          }
        });
        module.exports = router;
```

When ever i try to enter wrong user name then my node app crashes after giving "Wrong User Name"
message and this is the error i am having in the console and this only happens for user name but not for password.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')
    at D:\Web\React JS\e-commerce\API\Router\auth.js:31:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending multiple responses but can only send one response per request to the client.

Try this:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      username: req.body.username,
    });

    const hashedPassword = cryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      user.password,
      process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
    const originalPassword = hashedPassword.toString(cryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    const inputPassword = req.body.password;
    if (originalPassword !== inputPassword || !user) {
      res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");
    }


  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
    console.log(error);

  }
});
```

Comment: i have tried this code but still i am not getting "wrong user message". I am having empty brackets like this { } in postman